# Why does blocking on async in a Windows Service cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronizationcontext

I have an issue with deadlock in my code.

My code looks like this:

```
public async Task DoStuff(input)
{
    await AsyncMethod();
    //internally calls an async method, and blocks for its return. sometimes couses deadlocks. 
    new MyService().DoMoreStuff();
}
```

*MyService.DoMoreStuff* implementation :

```
DoMoreStuff()
{
    return DoSuffAsyncMethod().Result;
}
```

This code sometimes gives me deadlock on *DoSuffAsyncMethod*,

inside *MyService.DoMoreStuff* method.

If, however, I wrap the offending code in a task, dead locks no longer occur

```
public async Task DoStuff(input)
{
    await AsyncMethod();
    await Task.Run(new MyService().DoMoreStuff());
}
```

**More Info**

This code runs in the context of a windows service 
Thus , no synchronization context is involved.

I know how to solve the issue , yet still do not understand why the code would deadlock .

Can anyone suggest an explanation to the deadlocks of mixed sync async code , without synchronization context ?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments.

I am assuming it dead-locking.

Actual scenario is a little more complex , so I simplified it a little.

In *DoSuffAsyncMethod()* we are calling a remote async service , after some predefined time elapsed - we are timing out.

Analyzing the request and receiving service, revealed that messages are actually transmitted correctly .

So, barring network or network framework related issues , we are left with deadlock.

We assume it is deadlock , since once we restructured the code , the timeouts in *DoSuffAsyncMethod* went away.

**Edit 2**
The code

`DoSuffAsyncMethod().Wait().Result`

is wrong.

Correct code is

`DoSuffAsyncMethod().Result`

Issue was due to ConfigureAwait(true) being called deeper down the call stack .

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how do you know if its a deadlock if ther's no sync context involved?

Comment: I've improved your title for you - "async await deadlock" is not very descriptive of the problem.

Comment: `return DoSuffAsyncMethod().Wait().Result;` Are you sure it is actually a deadlock and not just this line waiting forever?

Comment: I am assuming it dead locking .

Comment: `.Wait().Result` won't compile, as `.Wait()` returns `void`.  Do you need to edit the question to correct it?

Comment: @alexsuchman: It is also possible to deadlock if you have a `TaskScheduler.Current` (other than `TaskScheduler.Default`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` basically means: "Hey `thread` go on doing your stuff, when I'm ready I'll ask for you to continue my job". The thread is like: "Yes, but I'll come to you when I've completed the rest of my work". Then you ask the thread to `Wait` the previous task, but it'll never complete the work because to complete it needs the thread to come back to him (yes, the thread that is Waiting for it...)

But when you do

```
await Task.Run(new MyService().DoMoreStuff());
```

The thread after `await` is available to resume the task that previously awaited (`DoMoreStuff()`), so they are both able to complete their work.

More info, and probably better explaination can be found [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: If I understand correctly  await **AsyncMethod();** will free the thread , and the thread will arrive at **"new MyService().DoMoreStuff();"** only once **AsyncMethod** completes . So , our thread arrive at **DoSuffAsyncMethod().Wait().Result** once await is completed.  Am I missing something ?

Comment: @alexsuchman Yes, but `DoSuffAsyncMethod()` is also an `async` method, so internally it `await` something. To continue it needs the thread to be free, but the thread is not free because it is running `Wait()` method.
So `DoSuffAsyncMethod().Wait().Result` never completes